# get_queryset method and ViewSets in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am doing exactly as the example states

here is my method

```
class FeedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Feed
    serializer_class = FullFeedSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = request.user
        queryset = Feed.objects.get_nearby(user)
        return queryset
```

when i execute it, it says request not defined .. which actually isn't. the example at [the rest framework's site](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets.html) also haven't defined request. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The request object is available (on either REST framework's class based views, or Django's standard class based views) as `self.request`.  You're missing the `self.` part of that.

Comment: hey tom, i figured it out, but the documentation misses the self. also :)

Comment: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets.html .. under the heading ModelViewSet , the code example has this mistake.

Comment: how to access request object in serializers or all the business logic should be done in views only ?

Comment: "how to access request object in serializers" - If you're using the generic views, then it'll be available on a serializer as `self.context['request']`. If you're not using the generic views then you'll need to make sure to pass `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.